# Serialization issue using Automapper and odata

Tags: odata, automapper

I am attempting to map an entity to a model like this

```
    public static AccountViewModel ToModel(this Account entity)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<Account, AccountViewModel>(entity);
    }
```

This is where I use this extension method

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<AccountViewModel> GetAccounts()
    {
        return _accountRepository.Table
            .Select(x => x.ToModel()).AsQueryable();
    }
```

I get the following exception

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Api.ViewModels.AccountViewModel ToModel(Data.Models.Account)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to do this

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<AccountViewModel> GetAccounts()
    {
        return _accountRepository.Table
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => x.ToModel()).AsQueryable();
    }
```

Comment: This is actually not very good for huge counts, as the ".ToList()" executes an SQL Query...